# How to do $\int e^\frac{-1}{2x^2}x^{-5}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to do $\int e^\frac{-1}{2x^2}x^{-5}dx$?

The original problem solve $xy'+\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^4}$

I simplified and found the integrating factor $e^\frac{-1}{2x^2}$ now the RHS of the equation is $\int e^\frac{-1}{2x^2}x^{-5}dx$

I have tried integration by parts with $u=e^\frac{-1}{2x^2}$ and $v=x^{-5}$ but this only seems to make it worse.

Comment: Try doing a $u$ substitution with $u=1/x$.

Comment: $1/(2x^2)$ is probably the better $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let t = $1/2x^{2}$

dt = $(-x^{-3}dx)$

So integration converts to 
$\int {e^{-t}(-2t)dt}$
Now apply by parts

and then substitute back t.

Comment: It took a some time to see where you are going with this but it helped thank you